# Looking for a faster way to perform SimpleImputer on pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I created this function to replace all np.nan values in a pandas df but the df is large and the run time is extremely high. I wonder if there is a better way to perform this?

```
  def clean_nan(data):

    data_val = data.values
    imp_med = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='median')
    imp_med = imp_med.fit(data_val)
    new_data = imp_med.transform(data)
    data[:] = new_data

    return final_data
```

Comment: Do you want DataFrame.fillna?

Comment: What about ```DataFrame.fillna()``` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! it worked perfectly and fast! 
BTW, as far as I know, in SimpleImputer func the nan value is imputed based on the column values. For example, if I'm choosing mean strategy, the nan value will be replaced by the mean of his column. Is there a way to preform the same with fillna()?